# Date Formatting to yyyymmdd in a TXT file

Tags: java

Converting User Input Date Format from `dd/mm/yyyy` to `yyyymmdd` to facilitate date checking. The code writes the date to a .TXT file but write it to it in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format when I'm wanting it in `yyyymmdd`. The method `ValidDate` is what I've tried to fix the problem so far but still isnt working. All help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Please try to format your code for increased readability including proper indentation, removing extra empty lines and removing irrelevant comments.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the parse to have a new date from string. Try change your validDate and execute a parse, like this:

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date theDate = df.parse(date);
    SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyymmdd");
    String formatedDateAsString = formater.format(theDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Where exactly would I place this code you have given me? just replace what I have in the ValidDate method with this? Sorry quite new to java. Thanks again.

Comment: @sr864 to your validateDate function.

Comment: You should create a new method, String dateConverter(String date), for example. Then on dateConverter method you make:  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  Date theDate = df.parse(date);
  SimpleDateFormat formatdate = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyymmdd");
  return formatdate.format(theDate); After, you can use this method to write on file: pw.println(dateConverter(formatdate)+","+litres+","+cost);

Comment: That all works apart from the last line when I amend the pw.println to that netbeans doesn't allow it and it says "Void type not allowed here" and gives me the option to Flip Operands. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks again

Comment: dateConverter(..) should returns the formatted string.

Comment: Still seems to not be working the only error that shows up is for the printwriter line

Comment: I've edited the original code at the top to what I have now

Comment: Buddy, try do not use variable with initial letter on uppercase. Maybe your IDE is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate
.parse(
    "23/01/2001" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" )
)
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE 
)
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/mZULS9).

> 20010123

Tip: Better to exchange date-time data textually using only the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats.

## *java.time*

You are using *terrible* date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes as of the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

### `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

### ISO 8601

Your desired output format is known as the "Basic" variation of the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. I suggest considering using the expanded variation, YYYY-MM-DD, as it is more recognizable and readable.

Also, the expanded variations are used by default in the *java.time* classes when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" ) ;  // Parsed by default, no need to specify a formatting pattern.
```